# Body Weight Converter

Tags: python, math, list-comprehension

I'm using TDD to build a Python function that takes in a string of separated, ascending bodyweights, for example `"103 123 4444 99 2000"`, and outputs the same numbers in the same string format BUT in ascending order according to their individual sums. Thus, the above input should have a result of `"2000 103 123 4444 99"`.

I've managed to break the parts down to what is needed to decipher the correct order based on input, however I'm unsure how to reorder the inputs based on the individual sums I've managed to calculate.

You'll notice on line 5 I'm using the wrong integers, as these are the sums, not the original inputs. This was just my attempt to visualize how to convert the list back to a string with single spaces.

```
def ordered_weight(strng):
    str_split = strng.split()
    int_split = list(map(int, str_split))
    sum_lst = sorted([sum(map(int, str(i))) for i in str_split])
    return ' '.join(str(x) for x in sum_lst)
```

One additional parameter a colleague presented:

> When two numbers have the same "weight", let us class them as if they were strings and not numbers: 100 is before 180 because its "weight" (1) is less than the one of 180 (9) and 180 is before 90 since, having the same "weight" (9) it comes before as a string.

Please help! Thank you!
MJ

Answer (score 4):

Use a key function that returns a tuple of the sum of the digits and the string itself

```
def ordered_weights(s):
    spl = s.split()
    spl.sort(key=lambda x: (sum(map(int, x)), x))
    return ' '.join(spl)
```

tuples are sorted such that if the first elements are equal then the second elements are compared and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line using list comprehension as follows:

```
' '.join([t for _,t in sorted(zip([sum([int(y) for y in x]) for x in s.split()], s.split()))])
```

Where `s` is the original input string.

**Output:**

```
'2000 103 123 4444 99'
```

With another example `s`:

```
s = "123 12 1561 613 63 126 74 2346 11 5612367 47 47 235"
```

**Output:**

```
'11 12 123 126 63 235 613 47 47 74 1561 2346 5612367'
```